# Should indexing category be small in this case?

Tags: category-theory

Fix a universe $\mathscr{U}$. Let $h:\mathscr{C}\rightarrow\text{Psh}(\mathscr{C})$ be the Yoneda embedding and $\mathscr{I}$ a category . We have the following result

> Let $\mathscr{I}$ be $\mathscr{U}$-small category and $F:\mathscr{I}\rightarrow\mathscr{C}$ a functor. Then $F$ has a
> limit iff the preheat $\lim_{i}\text{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(-,F(i))$ is
> representable.

Now I am given the following result as a corollary of the above:

> If every functor $F:\mathscr{I}\rightarrow\mathscr{C}$ has a limit,
> then the functor
> $\lim:\text{Func}(\mathscr{I},\mathscr{C})\rightarrow\mathscr{C}$ is
> right adjoint to
> $c:\mathscr{C}\rightarrow\text{Func}(\mathscr{I},\mathscr{C})$ (where
> $c(X)$ is the constant functor).

Cleary for the first result we need $\mathscr{I}$ to be $\mathscr{U}$-small category, otherwise the limit of $h\circ F\in\text{Psh}(\mathscr{C})$ is not guaranteed to exist. Do we also need $\mathscr{I}$ to be $\mathscr{U}$-small category for the corollary?

**Edit**: Nvm it has to be $\mathscr{U}$-small otherwise $\text{Func}(\mathscr{I},\mathscr{C})$ is not a $\mathscr{U}$-category.

Comment: Actually, the corollary is true without size restrictions. And it is a biimplication.